# Scheduling a job based on user input

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am building an web application with Phoenix and Elixir.  I want to implement a scheduling system, for example, I want the user to be able to say "I want to run this job at this date and time, and I want it to run once a week".

My question is, how would the system know that is has to run a job periodically on the date specified by the user.

I could poll a database every hour or so, and see if there are any jobs which need to run, but that leads to problems, for example the job would run later than the user wanted it to.

Thank you, help greatly appreciated!

Comment: How many potential users does your web application have?

Comment: @Aetherus let's say 1,000 for starters

Comment: That's not many. You can try spawning workers, one for each user, and supervise them with a `simpe_one_for_one` supervisor. If it scales, then maybe you can use `rabbitmq` with the `rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange ` plugin.

Comment: @Aetherus alright, I'll take a look into that!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [quantum package](https://github.com/c-rack/quantum-elixir). It should give you exactly what you want.